# AWS API Gateway How to access swagger documentation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway

Created API using AWS API Gateway and everything works just fine.

Question is: How can I access the generated API documentation from external clients (say Postman).
I know I can generate the Raw Swagger JSON using the API Gateway Console and I can consume it as RAW Swagger JSON in Postman, but I what I want is a URL I can provide to my Clients in order for them to download and import the swagger JSON definition of my APIs.

One post I was reading suggests hosting the swagger.json file on S3, but is this the best way? is there an out-of-the-box URL generated by the API Gateway automatically where I can just point any client at to consume the swagger JSON definition of my APIs?

Thanks.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @JoseMartinez I was not able to find an elegant solution. API Gateway does not provide URL for swagger documentation. Our solution was to manually dump the Swagger JSON definition (which you can grab directly from API Gateway Documentation section) into S3 static website (we have public hostname that map to this S3 bucket which was setup as part of the project). This means the consumer of our API would go to https://www.mycompany/project/api/vX.Y/swagger.json.
Again, not ideal solution nor it is elegant. It requires the swagger file to be updated manually (if API endpoints changes regularly).

Comment: 2021 and still no elegant solution?